# Flutter: MediaQuery.of() error when trying to style TextField in inputDecorationTheme under MaterialApp()

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to set inputDecorationTheme with some responsive fontSize and padding using MediaQuery, but getting following error :

**"MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery. No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you do not have a WidgetsApp or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.
The context used was: MyApp
"**

I have already gone through other posts having similar issue, but in my case I'm using MediaQuery inside ThemeData > inputDecorationTheme.

Note: I'm using separate file for accessing MediQuery.
Below is my code :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomeApp(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xff00bcd4),

        // TextFormField Decoration
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
          contentPadding:
             EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 2),
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Montserrat",
              fontSize: SizeConfig.textMultiplier * 2.3),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Montserrat",
              fontSize: SizeConfig.textMultiplier * 2.2),
          enabledBorder:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: custColor)),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.greenAccent),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: The media query is "introduced" by the material app, so you cant access is before its built. Would it work for you to set a static value in the font size and then do inputDecorationTheme.copywith(fonsize: your logic here), in the separate widgets that you need this?

Comment: the method you suggested may work, but that will not full fill my purpose. But anyways as you already told we cant access it before its built so ill remove my current approach of defining the fonts and padding. Thanks for the information.